What is the flammability of shatnez?
I recently learned that linen has a quality that enflames sparks - and is historically used as tinder.  On the contrary, wool is an extinguisher of flames.  I found that to be intriguing since Kohanim were the only ones who had specific exceptions and actual requirements to don garments that are classified as sha'atnez.  Therefore, I am curious as to what happens when shaatnez is burned.  Does it extinguish or last longer?  Are any of these qualities perhaps related to the chok of why sha'atnez is prohibited?

I am not sure it’s possible to answer the main question here. Presumably a material which is 90% wool 10% linen will have very different properties to a material which is 10% wool 90% linen. Both of these, however, are shaatnez.

@JoelK do we know what proportion was used in the avnet?

@DoubleAA acc. to Rashi (Yoma 71b elah me-avnet) it would seem to be 25% linen 75% wool. See also Tosafot to Shabbat 21a (simchat beit hashoeva) who says the same. Rambam (Hilchot K'lei Hamikdash 8:1) may have a different approach.

They used both the michnasayim (pure linen) and the avneitim (wool+linen) to light the lamps for the simchas beis hashoeivah

HESHY, When wool is mixed in it lights? I thought the two fabrics opposite re flame.  I'm researching symbolic properties and wondered RE implications linen="humble" wool=prestigious, linen flamable, wool extinguishes (hok/ polar opposites?), kohen  maintains purity of service, inspirs/leads tefilloh/tshuva, officiates to enable tshuva for the klal; sins of body and/or mind.  Since fire is such a part of the service it would be interesting to see if the kohanim's garments are symbolically related to that component of their duties.  Pls respond w/comments & or corrections to my question if any

@ALehodia i heard it also has to do with kayen killing helvel
